# Hash function in c++ for string to int

Tags: c++, string, hash

I am looking for a hash function in c++ to hash a string to an int. I used CMapStringToPtr but it has a function called "GetNextAssoc" that allows retrieving the key as string, meaning that the string must be stored and it gets so much memory. 
Is there any other hash function that gets less memory and does not store the string?

Comment: Try `std::hash<std::string>()()`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. In almost any place where you would use a hash function you are also going to have to track the original data because hash functions all have collisions and the original data is needed for a lookup based on the hash to be definitive, or to resolve collisions when they occur.

Comment: Yes but I do not need to keep the original data because of memory usage.. Also I do not want to resolve the collisions, Actually my goal is to keep the collisions!

Comment: I would use `boost::hash_value(const std::string & val)`

Comment: @Kerrek: [`std::hash<std::string>()()` seems to be a feature of C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash). I was out of luck with my Compiler (VS 2008).

Comment: @ChristianAmmer: Try `std::tr1::hash` then.

Comment: @Bipario: Interesting. Is this for a bloom filter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C++ has a built in hash function for this purpose - its used for all STL hash containers.

[`std::hash`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash)

PS: you can make your own too, just pass the string by const reference and cycle through its characters one by one, adding them to an integer, then mod by some value :)

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but your link refers to an SGI extension (defined in SGI <hash_map>) and was not part of the C++ standard before C++11 (where it's defined in <functional>).

Comment: Half-and-half I'd say.  I believe it's an extension but I'd be very surprised if it wasn't on your system - it's pretty much everywhere.

Comment: What do you mean by mod by some value?

Comment: @dustinyourface Mod means use the modulus operator: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html.  Giving some guidance on the subject from "Effective Java", for each significant field in the array, do "result = 31 * result + field".  You can initialize result to some random number like 17.  Using primes for the multiplier is recommended (supposedly it reduces collisions but the math is over my head).

Comment: `std:hash` returns `size_t` instead of `int` though

Answer (score 2):

```
 int hash( const string &key, int tableSize) {
   int hashVal = 0;

   for(int i = 0; i<key.length();  i++)
     hashVal = 37*hashVal+key[i];

   hashVal %= tableSize;

   if(hashVal<0)
     hashVal += tableSize;

   return hashVal;
 }
```